# Unbelievably Large Numbers in C++

Tags: c++, digits, large-data

Like the title says I'm in need of someway to store and compute with Integers in excess of 500,000 digits in C++. The operations that this program needs are: Divide(Integer), add, subtract, and modulus. Does anyone know of a library out there that can help me accomplish this?

Comment: GMP seems to be popular.

Comment: Does it hold numbers of the size im looking for?

Comment: Try it and find out. I doubt you'll have problems if others can.

Comment: 500K digits is about 1.5M bits, which is about 200K bytes. It should work, although I expect it will be really slow.

Comment: It will be slow regardless LOL, thanks for the input ill look into it.

Comment: Boost has three different options for multiprec, including a wrapper for gmp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GMP is what you want. There is no practical size limit to processing large integers or floating point numbers. GMP is capable of processing billions of digits, so you are well within the realistic range. It is primarily dependent on your system's architecture and available memory limitations.

http://gmplib.org/